# Como criar espaço antes ou no final do texto contido entre tags html?

Tags: html

Estou precisando colocar um espaço antes de um texto que se encontra entre tags `html`, qual é a forma correta de fazer ? Sem css...

```css
div{float:left;}
```

```html
<div>Texto 1</div><div>       texto que quero um espaço antes</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O problema de `&nbsp;` é que ele ajusta o espaçamento pelo tamanho da fonte (`font-size`), então para ajusta o layout é muito difícil, o que pode fazer é ajustar `margin` ou `padding`:

```css
.foo {
    float:left;
}
.bar {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Texto 1</div>
<div class="foo bar">texto que quero um espaço antes</div>
```

> qual é a forma correta de fazer? Sem css...

Seria usar CSS simplesmente para ajustar, não existe forma correta, afinal pode alcançar o efeito de varias maneiras e se dispensar o CSS em HTML é quase o mesmo que querer andar com um carro usando apenas as rodas e chassi, mas todo descoberto.

No basico em HTML fora o `&nbsp;` e `&emsp;` existe uma tag que pode ajudar a atingir o efeito, seria o `<pre>`, por exemplo:

```html
<pre>
foo bar                       foobar baz
</pre>
```

**Nota:** Todo motor de navegador já injeta um CSS tecnicamente no HTML, o que dá o formato padrão para as coisas, as vezes chamado de *user-agent-stylesheet*

---

### Quando usar os entities?

Existem entities para várias coisas, por exemplo:

- Acentuação
- Espaçamento
- Caracteres difíceis de escrever via teclado

Entenda que entities vieram antes do CSS ser tão funcional, antes o máximo que tínhamos era `font-size` e `color` no CSS, então dependíamos de coisas como:

- Muitos espaçamentos como `&nbsp;`
- Muitas quebras de linha com `<br>`
- Tabelas para fazer menus

O resultado disso geralmente eram HTMLs um pouco confusos.

Muitos desses `entities` ainda podem ser usados, mas hoje são perfeitamente substituídos por coisas mais praticas dentro do proprio CSS, em casos de acentos o `iso-8859-1` ou `UTF-8` se bem configurados não terá problemas.

Alguns carácteres difíceis são substituídos por ícones de fontes (woff, ttf, etc), ou se usa UTF8 em sua página tem muitos *emojis* que resolvem, claro que muitas coisas ainda podem ser feitas com `entities` que é bem mais simples.

Por exemplo, um espaço curto, com 3 `&nbsp;` já resolve, se tiver mais talvez seja melhor um elemento html, assim pode controlar pelo `width`:

```css
.space {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}

.signature {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px #000 dotted;
}
```

```html
<p>
Bla bla bla <span class="space"></span> Bla bla bla
Bla bla bla <span class="space"></span> Bla bla bla
Bla bla bla <span class="space"></span> Bla bla bla
</p>

<p>
Bla bla bla <span class="signature"></span> Bla bla bla
Bla bla bla <span class="signature"></span> Bla bla bla
Bla bla bla <span class="signature"></span> Bla bla bla
</p>
```

Se for a tag `<title>` e precisar de espaços pode simplesmente usar o `&nbsp;`:

```
<title>Carro&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Barco</title>
```

Claro que você tem que ter consciência que para SEO fazer títulos descritivos e reduzidos é fundamental, então dificilmente vai usar `entities` em títulos, a não ser que seja algo especifico.

Comment: certo, mas em quais casos seriam indispensáveis o uso de `entities` para espaço no html, existe essa exceção ?

Comment: @MagicHat as entidades veem antes do CSS ser tão funcional, vem de uma epoca aonde o que tinhamos de melhor era o `<br>` e o `<p>` e até tabelas para fazer as colunas do layout, hoje ele é dispensavel, a não ser quando vai escrever um texto, se bem que um elemento com `display: inline-block; width: <medida da separação>;` pode resolver muito melhor, e sem ficar preso a medida da fonte.

Comment: compreendo, mas ainda fico com a dúvida se há uma exceção...

Comment: @MagicHat pronto, editado novamente. Estava com alguns erros que impossibilitava entender o ultimo codigo.

Answer (score 7):

Não sei se existe o correto nesse caso, mas pode usar `&nbsp;`

Que renderiza um espaço em branco.

```css
div{float:left;}
```

```html
<div>Texto 1</div><div>&nbsp;texto que quero um espaço antes</div>
```

Ou ainda `&emsp;` que renderiza uma tabulação.

```css
div{float:left;}
```

```html
<div>Texto 1</div><div>&emsp;texto que quero um espaço antes</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `white-space: pre`:

```css
div {
  float:left;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div>Texto 1</div><div>       texto que quero um espaço antes</div>
```

De acordo com o [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp):

> **pre**: Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the `<pre>` tag in HTML

Ou seja:

> **pre**: Espaços em branco são preservados pelo navegador.O texto só será quebrado em quebras de linhas. Ele funciona igual a tag `<pre>`

Comment: Bem lembrado o `white-space`, +1.

Comment: Tem os outros atributos, mas acho que não convém citá-los: `pre-wrap`, `pre-line` e afins...

Comment: Sem dúvidas o `white-space` é a solução ideal para a pergunta, economizando e muito com visual do código.

Answer (score 5):

Dá para usar o `text-indent`.

```css
.indent {
  text-indent: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>Texto 1 <span class="indent">texto que quero um espaço antes</span></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Óras, use [**`margin`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) para isso:

```css
div { float: left }

div:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 6%
}
```

```html
<div>Texto</div><div>texto que quero um espaço antes</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

E `&emsp;` para inserir um espaço tab.

```css
div{float:left;}
```

```html
<div>Texto 1</div><div>&emsp;texto que quero um espaço antes</div>
```